# How to get a error message back from PowerShell in VBScript

Tags: powershell, debugging, vbscript, error-handling, exchange-server

I am running a PowerShell command like this in a VBScript.

Below is the VBScript I am running

```vb
'This Script is used for creating Mailboxes for Active Directory Users.
'This script triggers a Power Shell Script which creates the mailbox for the
'ActiveDirectory User.
'
Set args = WScript.Arguments
'Argument 0 contains the identity User Name
WScript.Echo args.Item(0)
'Argument 1 contains the Mail Store Alias Name
WScript.Echo args.Item(1)
'Argument 2 contains the Mail Database
WScript.Echo args.Item(2)
'Argument 3 contains the Report Log Path
WScript.Echo args.Item(3)

On Error Resume Next

Dim shell
Set shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

'Firing the PowerShell command from VBScript
shell.Run "PowerShell.exe -PSConsoleFile ""E:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\Bin\exshell.psc1"" -NoExit ""&{""Enable-Mailbox -Identity '"&Replace(args.Item(0),"'", "''")&"' -Alias '"&args.Item(1)&"' -Database '"&args.Item(2)&"';""exit 0""} ",,20

If Err.Number <> 0 Then 
    WScript.Echo("Error Occurred in CreateMailBoxExchange script" & Err.Description)
    WScript.Quit(2)
End If 
WScript.Quit(3)
```

So when `Enable-Mailbox` command fails it does not come back with the error message. How should I capture that message and send it back to the user?

Comment: try / catch Enable-Mailbox. Return a non-zero exit code when it doesn't work out. Document the meaning of the error codes or just log it. Inspect %LASTEXITCODE%. Or just move everything into PowerShell and get rid of the wrapper :)

Answer (score 1):

[`Enable-Mailbox`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa998251%28v=exchg.160%29.aspx) doesn't seem to return anything, but it should at least set the [automatic variable](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa998251%28v=exchg.160%29.aspx) `$?`, which indicates whether the last cmdlet was run successfully or not.

You could cast the boolean value of that variable to an integer and return that as the exit code:

```
Enable-Mailbox ...; exit [int]$?
```

What you currently have in your PowerShell command string (`...; "exit 0"`) doesn't do anything anyway, since it merely echoes the string `"exit 0"` without actually setting an exit code (so the default 0 is returned). But even if you removed the double quotes around that statement it would still always return 0.

By setting a proper exit code you can take the numeric value and convert it back to a boolean (`0`→`False`, `1`→`True`):

```
enabled = CBool(shell.Run("...", 0, True))
```

or just take the numeric value:

```
exitcode = shell.Run("...", 0, True)
```

However, for the latter you should invert the return value (`exit [int](!$?)`), since by convention a numeric exit status 0 indicates success, whereas numeric non-zero exit codes are used for signaling error states.